# html2image Can't convert correctly html text including Chinese characters

Tags: java

I use html2image to convert html to image, In my local macbook it wooks well.
but in the online centos server it just don't work

code

```
HtmlImageGenerator imageGenerator = new HtmlImageGenerator();
imageGenerator.loadHtml(rowHtml);
String fullPath = path+  market + dateFormat + ".png";
imageGenerator.saveAsImage(fullPath);
```

the html is something like `<table>...</table>`
I have tryed add the `<header> ...<meta charset='utf-8'>...`but it dosn't work
anyone help me?

in the online centos server the picture looks like 
[fail image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/067Om.png)

Comment: It's possible that the problem is the `path` ?

Comment: I think it's because the difference of mac and centos

Comment: What differences exactly? What I mean by path is if you did set an absolute path for finding in your mac, on your server you won't find them.

Comment: it's absolute path , and it generate a picture ,but in the picture, the chinese font did't normal, I think the difference of two system is font.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved the question 
In linux system we should add 
msyh.ttf ,
msyhbd.ttf,
simsunb.ttf, this three kind of fonts to the dir JRE_HOME/lib/fonts/fallback,and then

```
cd JRE_HOME/lib/fonts/fallback
sudo mkfontdir
sudo mkfontscale
```